# How to check if a date falls between two other dates in XPath

Tags: c#, date, xpath, event-log

I'm trying to pull event logs from a windows PC given certain information. This block of code is working fine but only pulls logs from the current day. I'd like to only pull logs that where created between dates that are specified earlier, "toDate" and "fromDate". This is my first time using xpath and I can't seem to find anything online that deals with something like this.

```
      string queryString = 
            "<QueryList>" +
            "  <Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"Application\">" +
            "    <Select Path=\"Application\">" +
            "        *[System[(Level=3) and " + 
            "        TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]" +
            "    </Select>" +
            "  </Query>" +
            "</QueryList>";
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the XML you're trying to query?

Comment: Very difficult in XPath 1.0, very easy in XPath 2.0. So you need to tell us which you are using (or whether this could be changed).